# Questionable question deletion

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What is the most efficient numerical base system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446664/what-is-the-most-efficient-numerical-base-system) was a perfectly good question that accumulated a few good references in the comments when the OP deleted it. What should be done in this sort of situation?

Comment: Maybe Requests for Reopen Votes thread can be used for Requests for Undelete Votes too? Just a thought. The more general thought is this is one of many reasons why answers should not be given in comments.

Comment: However, answers consisting only of links are discouraged, so that's a bit of a catch-22.

Comment: Correct. It is better to explain why  the hyperlinked resource  answers the question. If this is not done, then it's indeed a comment -- and the user should't be surprised if their half-baked contribution goes away at the whim of the OP. Comments are not considered to be of archival value.

Comment: 10k users can vote to undelete. The question already has 2 votes.

Comment: The question has been undeleted.

Comment: So, should **this** question be now deleted by the OP?

Comment: @40votes: No, because it has useful comments.

Comment: The deleted question has now been restored.

Comment: I think @40votes wanted to apply the duality theorem ;)